# using dict to replace values in a pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
0  column_1  column_2
1        Gm       tri
2       Boi        bi
3        Xv       tri
4        Gm        bi
5        Zl       uni
6        Oe       uni
```

I want to use the dict below to change the values in `col2`

```
dict_a = {'Gm':'tri', 'Boi':'bi', 'Xv':'uni', 'Zl':'uni', 'Oe':'bi'}
```

to look like this:

```
0  col1   col2
1   Gm     tri
2  Boi      bi
3   Xv     uni
4   Gm     tri
5   Zl     uni
6   Oe      bi
```

Comment: Have you tried [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['Gm', 'Boi', 'Xv', 'Gm', 'Zl', 'Oe'],
    'column_2': ['tri', 'bi', 'tri', 'bi', 'uni', 'uni']
})

dict_a = {'Gm': 'tri', 'Boi': 'bi', 'Xv': 'uni', 'Zl': 'uni', 'Oe': 'bi'}

df['column_2'] = df['column_1'].map(dict_a)
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
  column_1 column_2
0       Gm      tri
1      Boi       bi
2       Xv      uni
3       Gm      tri
4       Zl      uni
5       Oe       bi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (however mapping would likely be preferred):

```
import pandas as pd #using version 1.1.3

# build the df as described
occurrences=['Gm','Boi','Xv','Gm','Zl','Oe'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(occurrences,columns=['col1'])
df['col2'] = pd.Series(['tri','bi','tri','bi','uni','uni'] )

#set dict
dict_a = {'Gm':'tri', 'Boi':'bi', 'Xv':'uni', 'Zl':'uni', 'Oe':'bi'}

#replace col2 values
df['col2']=df.replace({'col1': dict_a})

#review results
df.head()
```

- dict:

  ```
    - For a DataFrame nested dictionaries, e.g.,
      ``{'a': {'b': np.nan}}``, are read as follows: look in column
      'a' for the value 'b' and replace it with NaN. The `value`
      parameter should be ``None`` to use a nested dict in this
      way. You can nest regular expressions as well. Note that
      column names (the top-level dictionary keys in a nested
      dictionary) **cannot** be regular expressions.
  ```

Comment: Have you tried it? It works perfectly fine. Also if you read the documents associated with replacing you would see the information around dictionaries and replacement.:

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, perhaps you have syntax (missing parens or brackets) issues or a different pandas version. More than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: This works fine for me too; +1 for both answers but imho, this is more readable due to "replace". But maybe the last item from the quote of documentation (which is used in the answer) can be higlighted..